# How to change the text 'Value' in Chartkick's geochart

Tags: google-visualization, chartkick

I am rendering a geochart with the following:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>

<%= geo_chart Company.group(:country).count, colors: ["#33C1FF", "#008ED6"] %>
```

This works great, but the text used on the map to specify the count for each country is 'Value'.

I am using the Google Charts API to do this, and looking at their documentation, they are able to use 'Popularity' instead of 'Value' by doing this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Popularity'],
      ['Germany', 200],
      ['United States', 300],
      ['Brazil', 400],
      ['Canada', 500],
      ['France', 600],
      ['RU', 700]
    ]);
```

I've tried to replicate this by adding it directly to geo_chart, and still 'Value' appeared. You can see my attempt below:

```
<%= geo_chart [['Popularity'], ['Germany', 200], ['United States', 300], ['Brazil', 400], ['Canada', 500], ['France', 600], ['RU', 700]], colors: ["#33C1FF", "#008ED6"] %>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the code on Chartkick and looks like this value was fixed. So instead I used the Google Geomap directly and was able to customise as required. Here's my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["geomap"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

  function drawMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Data Feeds'],
      <% Company.country_count.each do |key, value| %>
      ['<%= Company.country_name("#{key}") %>', <%= value%>],
      <% end %>
    ]);

    var options = {
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#33C1FF', '#008ED6']},
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
      datalessRegionColor: '#F5F5F5',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
      legend: 'none',
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('datafeeds_geomap'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  };
</script>

<div id="datafeeds_geomap" style="height: 300px; text-align: center; color: #999; line-height: 300px; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Loading...</div>
```